# Divide colums by other columns and itself depending on index in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(dddt_a = sample(1:1000, 1000, replace=T),
                 dddt_b = sample(1:1000, 1000, replace=T),
                 dddt_c = sample(1:1000, 1000, replace=T),
                 dddt_d = sample(1:1000, 1000, replace=T),
                 index = as.character(sample(c("a", "b"), 1000, replace=T)))
```

I want to divide each colum by either `dddt_a` or `dddt_b` depending on what the index is. If the index is `a` then divide all columns except the index by `dddt_a` and if `index==b` divide all columns except the index by `dddt_b`. The way it is set up now, this only divides `dddt_a` by `a` but not the other columns (likewise if `index==b`).

```
df1 <- df %>% 
      mutate_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("dddt")),
                .funs = list(~ifelse(index=="a", ./dddt_a, ./dddt_b)))

head(df1)

     dddt_a dddt_b dddt_c dddt_d index
1 1.0000000    686    474    756     a
2 0.7388466      1    681    726     b
3 1.0000000    218    570    448     a
4 2.0086393      1    830    958     b
5 1.0000000    989    590    128     a
6 1.0000000    128    978    144     a
```

A work around is storing the denominator variable outside, split the data for each index, divide everything and put it back together (I ran it only for `index==a` here). However, this should be possible in dplyr, I'm sure...?

```
ind_a <- df$dddt_a[df$index=="a"]

dfa <- df %>%
    filter(index=="a")%>%
    mutate_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("dddt")),
           .funs = ~ ./!!ind_a)
```

Related to what seems to be the same issue. In a nex step I want to sum the values up, again depending on the `index` variable:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
      mutate(SUMS = ifelse(index=="a", 
                   1+dddt_b+dddt_c+dddt_d,
                   1+dddt_a+dddt_c+dddt_d))
```

However, this sums all variables up...

```
head(df2)
     dddt_a dddt_b dddt_c dddt_d index     SUMS
1 1.0000000    686    474    756     a 1917.000
2 0.7388466      1    681    726     b 1408.739
3 1.0000000    218    570    448     a 1237.000
4 2.0086393      1    830    958     b 1791.009
5 1.0000000    989    590    128     a 1708.000
6 1.0000000    128    978    144     a 1251.000
```

But for the first row, for example, `SUMS` should be equal to 1916:

```
rowSums(df2[1,2:4]) #the result should be 1916 not 1917
1916
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column after dividing

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("dddt")),
            list(new = ~ifelse(index=="a", ./dddt_a, ./dddt_b))) %>%
  head

 #  dddt_a dddt_b dddt_c dddt_d index dddt_a_new dddt_b_new dddt_c_new dddt_d_new
#1     836    686    474    756     a      1.000      0.821      0.567      0.904
#2     679    919    681    726     b      0.739      1.000      0.741      0.790
#3     129    218    570    448     a      1.000      1.690      4.419      3.473
#4     930    463    830    958     b      2.009      1.000      1.793      2.069
#5     509    989    590    128     a      1.000      1.943      1.159      0.251
#6     471    128    978    144     a      1.000      0.272      2.076      0.306
```

If you want you can then select only `"_new"` columns or `rename` the `"_new"` column to names of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("dddt")),
        list(new = ~case_when(index=="a" ~ ./dddt_a, TRUE ~ ./dddt_b)))
```